# Really confused about MySQL join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've really been trying to figure this out myself, but all tutorials on the internet either doesn't work, or they are written half...  no one explains how you echo out the content.

right now I'm pulling a table of popular searches... I want to display the name, and then the category name underneath it. But problem is, that the searches table stores the categories as ID and not name.

So I need to use a join, that will link the "category_id" column in the "popular_search" table, to the "id" column inside the "categories" table... and then display the "name" column from the "categories" table to display the category name.

No one gives info on how to echo the content, cause both tables have columns with the same name, how do I actually do it? I don't get it...

This is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM popular_search ORDER BY `hits` DESC LIMIT 9
```

And this my current echo's, but I need to the replace the id field with the category name from the other table:

```
<?php echo $item['name']; ?>
<?php echo $item['category_id']; ?>
```

Comment: Your query doesn't have any JOIN in it...

Comment: If you want to understand JOINS you could read [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/), if you want to learn everything about JOINS read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `AS` should work for you:

```
SELECT
    ps.*,
    ca.name as `category_name`
FROM
    `popular_search` as `ps`
INNER JOIN
    `categories` as `ca`
ON
    ps.category_id = ca.id
ORDER BY
    ps.hits DESC
LIMIT 9
```

Now it'll be in your array as `category_name`.

You can read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: THANK YOU! You are my absolute HERO. I've been trying to figure this out for days!!! Have a blessed holiday season ;)

Answer (score 2):

Specify the column names in the SELECT (rather than SELECT *).

Give the coumn names alias names (ie, *SELECT a.Column1 AS **Fred*** , Fred being the alias)

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
popular_search ps
inner join categories c on (ps.category_id = c.id)

ORDER BY `hits` DESC LIMIT 9
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess, you need to know on table alias. So you can use two alias[new names] to two tables and refer them separately in select query.
As there are lot of examples, i wont re-write here them. please have a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp
[Table alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact thing that you are looking for 
  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Give it a try ..

Comment: kuldeep: by no means am I here to disciminate - I'm just saying that it isn't best practice to make new developers look at sites like W3Schools, and make them think of it as a valid source, as a lot of their content is flawed (see the link in my first comment).